# Possible to turn ON phone with ADB ? (Galaxy S6)

Tags: adb, samsung, fastboot, samsung-galaxy-s-6

I have a Samsung Galaxy S6 with a broken power button. (It only works occasionally)

Do you know if there is a way to use ADB (or any other way) to turn the phone on? (When it for some reason has shut down)

I have used "ADB devices" and "ADB reboot" which are working fine. (Tested with phone turned on)
However they do not work when the phone is off. (Phone still connected to PC and charging) The device is not detected.

I have not been able to find a solution myself. (None of the "long press methods" with volume buttons/home button etc. have worked on my phone)

I hope one of you have the knowledge I don't to turn on a S6 without the power button.
Thanks. :)

Device: Not rooted.
USB debubbing enabled.
Power button: Only working occasionally. (And of course not when the unit turns off)

Comment: I don't know a way to do that on Samsung devices other than through a modified kernel this will allow the phone to switch on while a cable is connected. If you're feeling adventuresome, it's pretty easy to fix the broken button yourself. > https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=i7P08tnlHBo

Comment: I don't know if it works on Samsung devices since they don't have a fastboot bootloader menu, but in Moto and some other devices you can hold VOL DN and connect USB to computer and the device will boot to the bootloader menu, and from there you can use the command `fastboot continue`

Comment: @acejavelin There's no such menu for Sammy devices unfortunately - there's no `fastboot` in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

No, ADB requires the phone to be on and be running a OS/Recovery to accept it. The bootloader uses fastboot which is only available there.

TL;DR No, when the phone is off it is not listening (by default, atleast) to commands from a PC.

EDIT: You may be better off jerry rigging something in it, is it the internal part bad or is it the external part?

EDIT2: People have pointed out that samsung does not even have fastboot (apparently) and that you COULD do something with a custom kernel, but that seems like alot of effort that may be better awnsered with `get a rma` or `get a new phone,` Sorry bro.